# bash: how to call command for all combinations of parameters

Tags: bash

I know I can print all combinations of parameters: `printf "%s\n" {{a,b,c},{A..Z}}` or `echo {1..4}{a,b}`

but i don't know what's the correct syntax to execute a command with all combinations of parameters. something like:

`./gradlew -i test -Dsome-param={a,b,c} -Dother-param={x,y,z}`

expected result is executing 9 commands:

```
./gradlew -i test -Dsome-param=a -Dother-param=x
./gradlew -i test -Dsome-param=b -Dother-param=x
...
./gradlew -i test -Dsome-param=c -Dother-param=z
```

Comment: Show how you want it to look expanded plz

Comment: i added expected result

Comment: Use loops, trying to do this with brace expansion will be a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
 for i in {a..c}; do for j in {x..z}; do ./gradlew -i test -Dsome-param="$i" -Dother-param="$j"; done; done
```